# Why is this table floating up above the section header?

Tags: tables, positioning

```
\section{Main section}

\subsection{Some subsection}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
x & y & z & a &  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Test text test text.
```

For some reason this table is shows up before "Main section" even though I typed it after the section header. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Because you put it into a floating environment? ;-) My usual answer for this: Drop the `table` environment and use `\captionof{table}{...}` instead of `\caption{...}`, this requires the `caption` package (which is a good idea anyway)

Comment: try `\begin{table}[!htb]`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer What is a "floating environment"?

Comment: Actually, even `\begin{table}[h]` is enough in this case.

Comment: @SeanHill: Look at your title: You have experienced what a floating environment is ;-)

Comment: Wow, [!htb] and [h] worked! What does that do and why did it resolve this issue?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer What constitutes a floating environment then? If I use \begin{equation} that seems to "stick" fine, but when I do \begin{table} suddenly it "floats" up to the top of a page?

Comment: @SeanHill: Unless defined otherwise, `figure` and `table` are the basic floating environments. Other packages define new ones or with the package `float` there will be new floats available, if really needed. I suggest to read an introductory book on `LaTeX`.

Comment: @SeanHill `h` means "here". If you add `tb`, it can be placed at the top of the current page (or next page) or at the bottom of the current page (or next page).

Comment: @Alenanno The option `[h]` is automatically changed into `[ht]`

Comment: @egreg Yeah, but not with all documentclasses, right? I mean, most of them.

Comment: @Alenanno It's done by the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: @Alenanno: the float mechanism is in `latex.ltx` already, so it's no special invention of a class. I think it's the same for all standard classes, but maybe I am wrong. Do you have an example?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Mh I had read so in an answer here time ago. I don't have a particular example. :P

Comment: @Alenanno: Well, it might be possible anyway...